# Which statement should I prove?

Tags: proof-writing, vectors

I have an exercise, but my problem is not directly related to how to solve it, but which statement do I have to prove.

The following is the exercise:

> b) Prove the following:
>
> $$||\lambda\vec{v}|| = |\lambda| \cdot ||\vec{v}||$$ 
>   $$||\vec{v}|| \geq 0,  \forall\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R^n}$$ 
>   $$||\vec{v}|| = 0 \iff \vec{v} = \vec{0}$$

The `a)` uses the same approach `prove the following` and then a lot of statements, and I don't know if I have to prove them all or what.

I managed to prove the first statement:

$$||\lambda\vec{v}|| = |\lambda| \cdot ||\vec{v}||$$

but the point is that I don't understand if I have also to prove the other statements or what, it's not clear.

Comment: You have to prove all the statements, I'm sure. :)

Comment: How so? As I see it, the first doesn't imply the second one.

Comment: Agreed. My point was just that this argument is independent from the first result, and that you have to prove all of them.

Comment: your argument for the second part is fine by me, but for the third part, it sounds like you are just re-stating what they want you to prove. It is indeed clear, but you should probably go over the argument anyway. So suppose first that $v$ is the zero vector. You can do the calculation to show that $||v||=0$. For the other direction, assume that $||v||=0$. I suggest writing this out in detail and pointing out why each coordinate $v_i$ must then be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prove all three statements. This seems part of an excercise to establish that something is a [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29), and thus you have various things that need to be checked.